# Receiving an empty table when using multiple on parameters and join in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I'm rather new to sql and I've been running through some basic exercises to learn more. I've been able to make all of my other joins return the answers I need, but this one still eludes me.

```
 Select invoice.num from invoice join customer
 on customer.code = invoice.code
 and customer.lastname = 'Smith'
 ;
```

Essentially I'm trying to find the invoice number for Smith, so I linked the two tables together using customer's primary key and the foreign key in the invoice table. That returned all of the invoice numbers for me, so when I added more parameters to filter only the those with last name smith, but I'm only getting an empty table returned to me. Is there a syntax error I'm unaware of, or is the problem in the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is syntactically and semantically correct. There is no rows in `customer` with `lastname = 'Smith'` or there is no rows in `invoice` with `code` equal to that `code` from `customer` table for `lastname = 'Smith'`. Note, a text comparison in Postgres is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you, you're completely right. I went back and checked in the tables and there was no match for Smith.